# RequireJS optimizer prepend

Tags: javascript, requirejs, r.js

I am looking for a way to prepend some information to minimized file.

I've found the option [here](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js#L478), but it doesn't useful for me because uglifier runs after the wrapper code has been added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could [assign a function to the `out` key](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/6391520ecb29eb51f4469859d06ed0bd2e09b625/build/example.build.js#L448-L457) to post-process the file. By setting this option, the result will not automatically be written to a file, so you have to do that yourself. For example:

```
({
    // Let's optimize mainApp.js
    name: "mainApp",
    optimize: "uglify",
    out: function(text) {
        // Transform the compiled result.
        text = '// Stuff to prepend \n' + text;

        var filename = 'outputfile.js';
        // By default, the name is resolved to the current working directory.
        // Let's resolve it to the directory that contains this .build.js:
        filename = path.resolve(this.buildFile, '..', filename);
        // Finally, write the transformed result to the file.
        file.saveUtf8File(filename, text);
    }
})
```

Note: In the previous snippet, [`file.saveUtf8File` is an internal RequireJS API](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/6391520ecb29eb51f4469859d06ed0bd2e09b625/build/jslib/node/file.js#L236-L239) and `path` is the [`path` module](http://nodejs.org/api/path.html) imported from Node.js standard library (only if you run `r.js` with Node.js, and not e.g. with Rhino or in the browser).

If you save the previous as `test.build.js`, create an empty file called `mainApp.js` and run `r.js -o test.build.js, then a file called "outputfile.js" will be created with the following content:

```
// Stuff to prepend 
define("mainApp",function(){});
```